# Laravel5.8 belongsTo relation not working for foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, belongs-to

I'm working on Laravel relation using hasMany and belongsTo. It work fine for `hasMany` relation but I have problem on `belongsTo` for collection foreach loop. This is my `categories` table.

```
    id    name
  --------------
    1     food
```

And `products` table.

```
    id    name         category_id
  ----------------------------------
    1     pizza          1
    2     hamburger      1
```

Below is `hasMany` product model.

```
# Product.php

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Below is `belongsTo` category model.

```
# Category.php

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id');
}
```

I got an error in blade:

> Trying to get property of non-object

```
 <tbody>
   @foreach ($products as $product)
      <tr>
           <td> {{ $product->category->name }} </td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the method defintion. The second parameter of the `belongsTo` method is the foreign key column name. Try this:

```
# Product.php

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

But, given that your foreign key is the model name followed by `_id` (`category_id`), Laravel will look up for this key by default.. so you could simplify it like this:

```
# Product.php

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse):

> ... In the example above, Eloquent will try to match the `post_id`
>   from the `Comment` model to an  `id` on the `Post` model. Eloquent
>   determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the
>   relationship method and suffixing the method name with a `_` followed
>   by the name of the primary key column. However, if the foreign key on
>   the `Comment` model is not  `post_id`, you may pass a custom key name
>   as the second argument to the `belongsTo` method:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Get the post that owns the comment.
>  */
> public function post()
> {
>     return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key');
> }
> ```

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution glad to help. You can now accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Category.php

```
public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Instead of 'id' in category() use 'category_id'..... as you have given category_id as foreign key ....so laravel will search for it...

Comment: Dear Varsha Jadhav, Thank you.